# Recover exFat partition

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, exfat, hybrid-mbr, fixmbr

I have been working on fixing my bootcamp partition, but in the process I make a big mistake. I ran 'bootrec /fixmbr' and bootrec /fixboot on the wrong disk. My data is now inaccessible, if not lost.

I have ran testdisk and it has found a partition, but it does not see any files. Rather than cause more damage I decided to come here.

The disk worked fine before I ran those commands. It was formatted as exFat. I am in the process of backing up the partition right now before I try anything further.

I can post any info that is requested. I am not currently at the computer but will be soon. Thank you.

Edit - Here is some more info -

```
diskutil list  
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER  
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1  
1:               Windows_NTFS                         750.2 GB   disk1s1  

sudo gpt -r -vvvv show /dev/disk1  
gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=750156374016; sectorsize=512; 
blocks=1465149168  
gpt show: /dev/disk1: MBR at sector 0  
gpt show: /dev/disk1: MBR part: type=7, start=2048, size=1465143296  
       start        size  index  contents  
           0           1         MBR  
           1        2047           
        2048  1465143296      1  MBR part 7  
  1465145344        3824
```

Testdisk

```
Disk /dev/rdisk1 - 750 GB / 698 GiB - 1465149168 sectors
Current partition structure:
 Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * HPFS - NTFS                 2048 1465145343 1465143296

Warning: Bad starting sector (CHS and LBA don't match)
```

Then

```
Warning: the current number of heads per cylinder is 1
but the correct value may be 128.
You can use the Geometry menu to change this value.
It's something to try if
- some partitions are not found by TestDisk
- or the partition table can not be written because partitions overlap.
```

Next Screen

```
  HPFS - NTFS                 2048 1465145343 1465143296
Invalid FAT boot sector
     0 D FAT16 >32M            1109994229 1865553126  755558898
         FAT16 >32M            1109994229 1865553126  755558898
```

Comment: Neither fixmbr nor fixboot would cause the problem you describe. Do you have any other ideas about what you did?

Comment: 1) Prevent any write to the disk!!! 2) Make its sector-by-sector copy 3) Try to recover files to a separate disk using any euristic recovery software. PS. The problem seems not to be related to fixmbr/fixboot execution, it looks like a damage by incorrect detouch.

Comment: @Appleoddity Reblessed reFind, it worked after this though. After the bootsec commands the laptop ceased to respond to holding down option to select the disk at boot OR enter refind, just boots straight to OSX. I added more info above.

Comment: @Akina I imaged the disk in disk utility, I am not sure if that is a sector by sector copy. I cannot see the partition in other software, should I run dd?